# Is the order of an unordered_map deterministic?

Tags: c++, dictionary, deterministic, unordered

I'm wondering if there's any guarantee that the order of an unordered_map will always be the same across all CPUs, threads, etc.

I realize there may be no obvious pattern to the particular order itself (hence, 'unordered' map), but if I run my process on another machine, or multiple times in succession, or on different threads, will the order of inserted items always be the same if the hash functions and insertion order remains the same? In other words, if my code doesn't change, will every execution of my process result in the elements of the map being in the same order?

I've run a few tests, and the order of items after insertion seems to be the same each time, but that could merely be a fluke, and I only have this single machine to test on. I need to know whether the order can be influenced by any other factors such as CPU/memory architecture, OS (Windows 8 vs Windows 10), etc.

Comment: Across every possible constellation of implementations? Of course not. That would be way to restrictive on the standards part. Furthermore, the very name of the type specifies you *may not* assume a specific order...

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm not asking about consistency across implementations, only consistency across wherever/whenever my compiled code happens to run. Also my question doesn't contradict the name of the container...as an analogy, there are (p)RNGs that are deterministic. If someone asked if they should expect the same sequence of random numbers from the same seed, it wouldn't make sense to answer "the name implies no".

Comment: Just use `boost.multiindex` so you can have predictable order of elements and access by hash.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**: It can be done, but I wouldn't recommend it. Use another data structure if you can; your own hash table, a "treap", a flat array, or something.

The order of items in an `std::unordered_map` (or set) is more dependent on the standard library implementation than hardware/CPU/etc.

For that reason, if you use the same library implementation across different hardware, and provide your own hash function (to make sure it's not randomized across runs - to combat DoS attacks against your data structures,) or otherwise hardware- or OS-dependent, then you should be fine.

However, if you are looking for a guarantee in the standard, you won't find any. The only relevant guarantee is that in the same instance of the object, the same key will hash to the same bucket. I don't think there is a guarantee even for different instances of the map, and I know from (painful) personal experience that there is no consistency across different runs of the application.

But not all hope is lost! If you stick to the same implementation of `unordered_map`, and use your own hash functions, and take a look at the implementation to make sure there are no hidden surprises (any dependency on hardware/OS/time/RNG/etc. should be relatively easy to spot) you can manage it.

Note that since you seem to be on Windows and probably using MSVC, the default `unordered_map` with the default hashing algorithm is *not* at all order-consistent across runs of the same compiled binary (at least it wasn't in 2013/2015 IIRC.)

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you are serious about consistency, you have to make sure you link against the CRT *statically*. If you link against the DLL version, some future patch/update can change the behavior for your application after you release it.

Comment: Thanks @yzt, "there is no consistency across different runs of the application" is my biggest concern.

Comment: @Tyson, that's the default behavior; I think you'll be OK if you use your own hash. Read through the code, and then test to make sure!

Answer (score 2):

I got the different output orders when running the following code in different hardware platforms.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct hash_func {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::string &key) const {
        std::size_t hash = 0U;
        const std::size_t mask = 0xF0000000;
        for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < key.length(); ++i) {
            hash = (hash << 4U) + key[i];
            std::size_t x = hash & mask;
            if (x != 0)
                hash ^= (x >> 24);
            hash &= ~x;
        }
        std::cout << "for key " << key << " hash " << hash << std::endl;

        return hash;
    }
};

void show() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("n1YxyaBzoRogNh72eri7HBGijCAtcHpf9nm,");
    v.push_back("n1GV9UScgncwU6KKL9T18mCo2S6uAE69SWs,");
    v.push_back("n1X2SXyEKej7GZgAreXDCkiT59qaYKBDcYi,");

    std::unordered_set<std::string, hash_func> s;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
        s.insert(*it);
    }

    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    show();

    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

**1) Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz**

```
for key n1YxyaBzoRogNh72eri7HBGijCAtcHpf9nm, hash 43411516
for key n1GV9UScgncwU6KKL9T18mCo2S6uAE69SWs, hash 93983804
for key n1X2SXyEKej7GZgAreXDCkiT59qaYKBDcYi, hash 17984604
n1X2SXyEKej7GZgAreXDCkiT59qaYKBDcYi,
n1GV9UScgncwU6KKL9T18mCo2S6uAE69SWs,
n1YxyaBzoRogNh72eri7HBGijCAtcHpf9nm,
```

**2) AMD EPYC 7501 32-Core Processor**

```
for key n1YxyaBzoRogNh72eri7HBGijCAtcHpf9nm, hash 43411516
for key n1GV9UScgncwU6KKL9T18mCo2S6uAE69SWs, hash 93983804
for key n1X2SXyEKej7GZgAreXDCkiT59qaYKBDcYi, hash 17984604
n1X2SXyEKej7GZgAreXDCkiT59qaYKBDcYi,
n1YxyaBzoRogNh72eri7HBGijCAtcHpf9nm,
n1GV9UScgncwU6KKL9T18mCo2S6uAE69SWs,
```

Comment: The difference will come from the software implementation, not the CPU.

Comment: you mean the compiler? I used the same compiler, llvm-6.0.1.

Comment: The combination of a specifically packaged version of a specific toolchain on a specific operating system, yes. They can be configured in different ways. And there can be "chance" elements. But it's not the CPU unilaterally deciding any of this; it has no concept of C++ containers.